# instagram next page json link?

Tags: json, url, web, instagram

normal instagram json url: https://www.instagram.com/fragranticaofficial/?__a=1

and {"has_next_page": true, "end_cursor": "AQBRFDVvxk4K4zKp4RkiDq9O1RyH1nHRZyHyNG5-iMnGFAXXbnHCeU1upa3VFQ3qDnYj4aw5DpJNR6TR7Dzl3i-lls6B-Yaz1-tvdggLH_9e4g"}},

https://www.imgrum.one/piter.life.style this web page use next page.

Help me what is next page url ? how can I find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `end_cursor` and put it as a `max_id` param to query next page, until empty `end_cursor` gets. This is an example to query the next page items.

```
https://www.instagram.com/fragranticaofficial/?__a=1&max_id=AQBRFDVvxk4K4zKp4RkiDq9O1RyH1nHRZyHyNG5-iMnGFAXXbnHCeU1upa3VFQ3qDnYj4aw5DpJNR6TR7Dzl3i-lls6B-Yaz1-tvdggLH_9e4g
```

Comment: Should work with comments in a post too? I'm trying but I'm getting always only the comments from the first page

Comment: @noorh Sorry, it's been a long time since I worked with instagram api. I don't know how it is working today.

Answer (score 1):

For me put `end_cursor` in `max_id` not go to query next page.